# Control Order of Nodes When Using "Re-Layout Page" in Visio 2010

Tags: visio

Sorry, this probably isn't the most ideal venue for asking this question, but I couldn't find a better SE site.

When I use "Re-Layout Page", the nodes at the same level (hierarchically) are scrambled, and I can find no way to control them.

Fixing them all once via renaming the nodes didn't work. The order they're created in and the z-index of the object don't seem to matter either.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's tedious, but you have to select each connector one at a time (note: not each shape), in the order you want and "bring it to front." My drawing is a top-down tree, and I started from the (what I wanted to be) the leftmost leaf, worked up to the root (top) and then down the other side, staying connected the whole way. After setting the order this way, deselct everything and do the re-layout.

In general, any shape you want to move to the right, select its connector and "bring to front." But unless you do them all systematically, it will be hard to set an overall order this way.

I also tried to speed up the process by multi-selecting the connectors in the desired order, and then doing just a single "bring to front." However, I couldn't figure out what orderings this was producing. And there's the danger that you miss when control-clicking on a connector and you figure you should start over because the "order" isn't being set any more.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That did help, but I'm really annoyed by the lack of good node order controlling in Visio. This is truly awful for large diagrams...

Comment: Confirming that this still seems to be the preferred method 5 years later in Visio Professional 2013. I tried using dynamic connectors to set left-to-right dependencies (which I assumed I could then delete), but that didn't work.